# Appending variable length columns in Pandas dataframe Python

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas, multidimensional-array, dataframe

I have a few csv files which contain a pair of bearings for many locations. I am trying to expand the values to include every number between the bearing pairs for each location and export the variable lengths as a csv in the same format.

Example:

```
df = pd.read_csv('bearing.csv')
```

Data structure:

```
     A         B           C         D           E            
0    0         94          70        67          84       
1    120       132         109       152         150
```

Ideal result is a variable length multidimensional array:

```
     A         B           C         D           E            
0    0         94          70        67          84       
1    1         95          71        68          85  
2    3         96          72        69          86
...
n    120       132         109       152         150
```

I am looping through each column and getting the range of the pair of values, but I am struggling when trying to overwrite the old column with the new range of values.

```
for col in bear:
    min_val = min(bear[col])
    max_val = max(bear[col])
    range_vals = range(min(bear[col]), max(bear[col])+1)
    bear[col] = range_vals
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Comment: `pandas` dataframes need each column to be the same length, there's no real way around this. You can create separate `Series` for each range, otherwise I'm not sure how to achieve what you're trying to do. If you did have these variable length columns in the same dataframe, what would it mean for sets of values in the different columns to be in the same row? Do the rows imply any kind of relationship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dict` comprehension with [`min`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.min.html) and [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.max.html) in `DataFrame` contructor, but you get a lot `NaN` in the end of columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({col: pd.Series(range(df[col].min(), 
                                        df[col].max() + 1)) for col in df.columns })
print (df)
```

```
print (df)

       A      B     C     D      E
0      0   94.0  70.0  67.0   84.0
1      1   95.0  71.0  68.0   85.0
2      2   96.0  72.0  69.0   86.0
3      3   97.0  73.0  70.0   87.0
4      4   98.0  74.0  71.0   88.0
5      5   99.0  75.0  72.0   89.0
6      6  100.0  76.0  73.0   90.0
7      7  101.0  77.0  74.0   91.0
8      8  102.0  78.0  75.0   92.0
9      9  103.0  79.0  76.0   93.0
10    10  104.0  80.0  77.0   94.0
11    11  105.0  81.0  78.0   95.0
12    12  106.0  82.0  79.0   96.0
13    13  107.0  83.0  80.0   97.0
14    14  108.0  84.0  81.0   98.0
15    15  109.0  85.0  82.0   99.0
16    16  110.0  86.0  83.0  100.0
17    17  111.0  87.0  84.0  101.0
18    18  112.0  88.0  85.0  102.0
19    19  113.0  89.0  86.0  103.0
20    20  114.0  90.0  87.0  104.0
21    21  115.0  91.0  88.0  105.0
22    22  116.0  92.0  89.0  106.0
23    23  117.0  93.0  90.0  107.0
24    24  118.0  94.0  91.0  108.0
25    25  119.0  95.0  92.0  109.0
26    26  120.0  96.0  93.0  110.0
27    27  121.0  97.0  94.0  111.0
28    28  122.0  98.0  95.0  112.0
29    29  123.0  99.0  96.0  113.0
..   ...    ...   ...   ...    ...
91    91    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
92    92    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
93    93    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
94    94    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
95    95    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
96    96    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
97    97    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
98    98    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
99    99    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
100  100    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
101  101    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
102  102    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
103  103    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
104  104    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
105  105    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
106  106    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
107  107    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
108  108    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
109  109    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
110  110    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
111  111    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
112  112    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
113  113    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
114  114    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
115  115    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
116  116    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
117  117    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
118  118    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
119  119    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
120  120    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
```

If you have only few columns, is possible use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': pd.Series(range(df.A.min(), df.A.max() + 1)),
                   'B': pd.Series(range(df.B.min(), df.B.max() + 1))})
```

EDIT:

If `min` value is in first row and the `max` in last, you can use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({col: pd.Series(range(df[col].iloc[0], 
                                        df[col].iloc[-1] + 1)) for col in df.columns })
```

**Timings**:

```
In [3]: %timeit ( pd.DataFrame({col: pd.Series(range(df[col].iloc[0], df[col].iloc[-1] + 1)) for col in df.columns }) )
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.75 ms per loop

In [4]: %timeit ( pd.DataFrame({col: pd.Series(range(df[col].min(), df[col].max() + 1)) for col in df.columns })  )
The slowest run took 5.50 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100 loops, best of 3: 2.18 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works a treat